# Problem with FlexUnit4

Tags: actionscript-3, flexunit

I"m a bit confused because FlexUnith 4's behavior. When I use fail() in try-catch body fail method is just ignored.

```
[Test]
        public function extend():void
        {   
            try {
                fail("This should fail");                   
            } catch(er:Error) {}

        }
```

I suppose this one should fail as there is no way around it, but it  succeeds and turns green. Whatam I doing wrong? When i put fail() before try-catch block it fails as it is suposed to.  BTW using Flash builder 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way assertions are signaled to the framework is through exceptions. `fail` sends the failure signal using an exception too. That, and the fact that `Error` is the base class for all exceptions means that no exception will ever reach the framework (your `try`/`catch` block catches all excpetions), which means that the test didn't fail.

Comment: Thank you. And if you could me help with one more thing as I"m new to AS3 - how can I catch Null pointer exception, I just can"t find something similar to Java' NulPointerException..